# Update nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

A course `has_many` students and student `has_many` courses

Using a json API how would we update `course` to assign multiple students to a course

## Model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_students
  has_many :students, through: course_students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_students
  has_many :courses, through: course_students
end

class CourseStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```

## Controller

```
class CoursesController < SessionsController
  def update
    if @course.update_attributes(course_params)
      puts "students should now be added to course"
    end
  end

  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:description, :status, course_students_attributes: [:id], course_jobs_attributes: [:id])
  end
end
```

Am I on the right path?

Comment: I think you either need has_and_belongs to many(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).  If not then you need has_many_through.

Answer (score 0):

If your relationship is many to many, you are missing the keyword through in the association declaration:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, through: :course_students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, through: :course_students
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Also be careful with accepts_nested_attributes_for, specially with validations. Here you can read more: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the trouble but I did do this in my business code. The example I provided however I forgot to add this bit., Sorry!